# Update the list of clients online

Tags: java, multithreading, client-server, rsa, public-key

I'm writing a server in java which listens at a particular port. Different clients send messages to the server at regular intervals.

The messages contain the respective public keys of the clients.

The server has a list of public keys.

If the newly received public key is not present in the list, the server adds it there.

I have done the part of comparing the public keys and writing the public key not present in the list.

Code for multithreaded server (here the server actually listens at two different ports) :

```
while(!isStopped()){
        System.out.println("Server is working");
        try {
                serverSocket = ServerSocketChannel.open();
                serverSocket.configureBlocking(false);
                serverSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(serverPortRequest));
                serverSocket.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);
                serverSocket = ServerSocketChannel.open();
                serverSocket.configureBlocking(false);
                serverSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(serverPortAccept));
                serverSocket.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);

                while(selector.isOpen()){
                    selector.select();
                    Set<SelectionKey> readyKeys = selector.selectedKeys();
                    Iterator<SelectionKey> iterator = readyKeys.iterator();
                    while(iterator.hasNext()){
                        SelectionKey key = (SelectionKey) iterator.next();
                        if(key.isAcceptable()){
                            SocketChannel client = serverSocket.accept();
                            (new Thread(new WorkerRunnable(client,"Multithreaded Server"))).start();
                        }
                    }
                }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

The WorkerRunnable thread is where I check if the client's public key is already in the server's list or not :

```
if(!isPresent(userPK)) {
        FileOutputStream pk;
        try {
            pk = new FileOutputStream("contactsPK/contact"+Server.pkCounter++);
            pk.write(userPK);
            pk.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Here `userPK` is a `byte` array which stores the public key obtained from the message sent by a client.

How do i check at regular intervals (say 30 seconds) that a client, from the list of clients, has not sent the server a message? I would like to delete that client i.e. its public key from the list of stored public keys of the server.

Answer (score 1):

That's a really great question!

You're almost there with what you're trying to achieve, you just want to be careful about a couple of gotchas!

You start off your code with:

```
 while(!isStopped()){
 ...
 }
```

Which is a way of ensuring that you're consistently listening in on a port, but what you're also doing is creating a mutex lock for that process. You can read up on it here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion

What that will do is ensure that no other processes have access to the processor while you're running this code. With that,  unfortunately you'll see that as you start to scale your code up and add on functionality, this loop will prevent you from decoupling your code, ensuring robustness, and adding functionality (I'll get back to this later!). First what you'll want to do is use a web framework for your application, this can be done using a plethora of different options. Here are two resources which can help you decide:

http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/the-curious-coders-java-web-frameworks-comparison-spring-mvc-grails-vaadin-gwt-wicket-play-struts-and-jsf/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_application_frameworks#Java

I would reccommend starting off with the Spring MVC framework, it's the most generic and widely used these days and you'll have ample resources online to help you get started.

Once you've picked your framework, you're going to want to create an MVC architecture web application, here are a couple of resources:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller
http://blog.codinghorror.com/understanding-model-view-controller/

Your View isn't going to consist of too much, and in fact it can act as to just pass the public key along to your back-end (your controller and your model).

With the above mentioned, you can get rid of all the code that is looping and waiting to hear a ping from your ports, you can simply specify which ports to listen to in your Spring MVC configuration files.

Now for the fun part! You asked:

```
 "How do i check at regular intervals (say 30 seconds) that a client, from the list of clients, has not sent the server a message? I would like to delete that client i.e. its public key from the list of stored public keys of the server."
```

This can be achieved via two stores in your back end: redis - a session based key store, and a simple relation database of your flavor.

Your Algorithm can go simply as follows:

```
 1. Every time your view forwards the information of a request to your backend, add it to your redis database, in the form <id, key>

 2. Simply create a thread to run every 30 seconds to do:
     2a. get the list of id's from redis
     2b. perform a left outer join on table a and b, where A is your sql table of ids, and B is the list of ids from redis.  A left outer join returns all the values from an inner join plus all values in the left table that do not match to the right table. Here is a resource for SQL Joins: http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/
     2c. The result of the join is your final answer, be sure to store this in your db.
     2d. purge all keys from redis (this is a one-liner)
```

You can create a thread to run every 30 seconds on your backend using ScheduledExecutorService as follows:

```
 ScheduledExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
 exec.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
 @Override
 public void run() {
     // 2a from above: (get the list of id's from redis)
     // 2b from above (perform a left outer join on table a and b, where A is your sql table of ids, and B is the list of ids from redis.  A left outer join returns all the values from an inner join plus all values in the left table that do not match to the right table.)
     // 2c from above (The result of the join is your final answer, be sure to store this in your db)
     // 2d from above (purge all keys from redis (this is a one-liner)
}
}, 0, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Since this is a very concrete and repeatable task, you do have a couple of other options which have tradeoffs associated with them. You could create a crontab job which can execute a script which does the above, or even use triggers which are built into many relational databases's capabilities. The main down side to both is that you would be loosing code visibility as you choose to do so.

I also mentioned above about de-coupiling. Coupling (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming) is a very important concept as you begin to write code which scales. You want to keep code as loosely coupled as possible (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling) beacuse it's going to make debugging and make writing in a OOP fashion much easier for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I shall try to implement your suggestions and get back in case of problems.